# Python printing lines from a file

Tags: python, file, for-loop, printing

Salutations, I am trying to write a function that prints data from a text file line by line. The output needs to have the number of the line followed by a colon and a space. I came up with the following code;

```
def print_numbered_lines(filename):
    """Function to print numbered lines from a list"""
    data = open(filename)
    line_number = 1
    for line in data:
        print(str(line_number)+": "+line, end=' ')
        line_number += 1
```

The issue is when I run this function using test text files I created, the first line is not on the same indentation level as the rest of the lines in the output, ie. the outputs look kind of like 
`1: 9874234,12.5,23.0,50.0
    2: 7840231,70,60,85.4
    3: 3845913,55.5,60.5,80.0
    4: 3849511,20,60,50`

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Accept an answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the value of `end` argument with empty string instead of space. As `end` argument is a space, it's printing a space after every line. So latter lines have a space at the beginning of the line.

```
def print_numbered_lines(filename):
    """Function to print numbered lines from a list"""
    data = open(filename)
    line_number = 1
    for line in data:
        print(str(line_number) + ": " + line, end='')
        line_number += 1
```

Another way you can do this, is `strip` the new lines and print without passing any value to `end` argument. This will remove the `\n` it has at the end of the line and a new line will be printed as `end="\n"` by default.

```
def print_numbered_lines(filename):
    """Function to print numbered lines from a list"""
    data = open(filename)
    line_number = 1
    for line in data:
        print(str(line_number) + ": " + line.strip("\n"))
        line_number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified `end` argument as a space. So after first line each has this extra space.

line that your read from file looks somehting like this:

```
'9874234,12.5,23.0,50.0\n'
```

Look at the ending. Line translation happens is due to original line.

So to get what you want you just need to change `end`  argument of print to empty string( not space)

Moreover, I advise you to change the implementation of the function and use `enumerate` for line numbering.

```
def print_numbered_lines(filename):
    data = open(filename)
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        print(str(i+1)+": "+line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your print statement.

`print(str(line_number)+": "+line, end=' ')`

You probably saw that when printing your lines there was an extra line between them and then you tried to work around this by using `end=' '`.

If you want to remove the 'empty' lines you should use `line.strip()`. This removes them.

Use this:

`print(str(line_number)+": "+line.strip())`

strip can also take an argument. This is from the documentation:

> **str.strip(**[chars]**)**
>
> Return a copy of the string with the **leading and trailing characters removed**. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument **defaults to removing whitespace**. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

**Whats up with that?**

The lines in your file are not separated into different lines by nothing. On linux a newline is represented by `\n`. Normal editors convert these by pushing the text down into a new line.

When reading a file Python separates lines on exactly these `\n` but doesn't throw them away. When printing they will be interpreted again and combined with the newline a `print` adds there will be one newline 'too much'.

The `end` parameter in your print statement simply changes what `print` will use after printing a line. Default is `\n`.

Check what it does when you use `end=" !"`:

```
1: aaa
 !2: bbb
 !3: ccc
```

You can see the `\n` after 'aaa' causing a newline (which is part of the string) and after that print adds the contents of `end`. So it adds a `!`. The next line is printed in the same line because there is no other newline that would cause a line break before printing it.